# Ckan install fails with: Unknown distribution option: 'message_extractors'

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ckan

I am installing build CKAN in a virtual environment. I had problems installing some modules.

```
(default)[ckan@localhost ~]$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/ckan/ckan.git@ckan-2.6.0#egg=ckan
Obtaining ckan from git+https://github.com/ckan/ckan.git@ckan-2.6.0#egg=ckan
  Updating ./default/src/ckan clone (to ckan-2.6.0)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ckan
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'message_extractors'
      warnings.warn(msg)

    no previously-included directories found matching '.git'
    warning: no files found matching 'CHANGELOG.txt'
    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'ckan_deb'
Installing collected packages: ckan
  Running setup.py develop for ckan
    /usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'message_extractors'
      warnings.warn(msg)

    no previously-included directories found matching '.git'
    warning: no files found matching 'CHANGELOG.txt'
    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'ckan_deb'
    Creating /usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ckan.egg-link (link to .)
    ckan 2.6.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
    Installing ckan-admin script to /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin

    Installed /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan
Successfully installed ckan
Cleaning up...
(default)[ckan@localhost ~]$ pip install -r 
default/src/ckan/requirements.txt 
(...) 
Cleaning up... Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in 
/usr/lib/ckan/default/build/funcsigs Storing complete log in 
/usr/lib/ckan/.pip/pip.log
```

[Full pip.log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/LeonanCarvalho/df26504846df4a74706605f6fb2acae9/raw/fcb70c25084c3540b2a4167020305d70a0bd1389/pip.log)

After suppose "Successfully installed ckan" should have this command (virtual env)

```
(default)[ckan@localhost ~]$ paster
-bash: paster: command not found
```

Another informations:

- Python 2.7.5
- pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python2.7)
- OS: Centos7  Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 18 13:06:36 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Pip installed packages(virtualenv):

  - appdirs (1.4.0)
  - ckan (2.6.0, /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan)
  - packaging (16.8)
  - pip (1.4.1)
  - pyparsing (2.1.10)
  - setuptools (34.1.1)
  - six (1.10.0)
  - wsgiref (0.1.2)

Comment: Author couldn't reproduce the problem

Comment: Updating setuptools solved the build problem, but I still have same warnings .

Comment: The warning about 'message_extractors' is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is complaining about the setuptools version only being 0.9.8 when funcsigs wants setuptools 17.1 or newer.

I'm not clear where this is specified in funcsigs, indeed I just installed it ok with setuptools version 2.2, so I'm not sure what's going on here. Maybe the log is misleading and something else is requiring a newer version of setuptools. Anyway, CKAN is perfectly happy with the latest setuptools version, so just do upgrade it.

Simplest way to try upgrading setuptools is:

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

Comment: So should I make a downgrade ? My setuptools version is 34.1.1

Comment: If that is indeed the version used when you used pip then I just don't know how to square that with the error message `pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 0.9.8 (/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=17.1'))`.

Comment: I'll mark that as correct, I made a new install because I couldn't fix that.
On log setuptools appears like 0.9.8 but on list command as 34.1.1.